# NodeJS callbacks: tracking db calls so I can terminate the process

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose, semaphore

I got a bill from Heroku this month, much to my surprise. It was only a few dollars, luckily, but I didn't think my usage had been that high. I checked the bill and it said I'd used about 1000 hours last month. I was briefly confused, since my app just runs for a few seconds every hour to send some emails, but then I realized that the process just wasn't terminating.

After commenting out swaths of my code, I've determined that the process doesn't exit because my mongoose database connection is still open. But I've got several nested callbacks to the database and then to mailgun to send these emails, and sometimes the mailgun callback has its own mailgun callback. How do I keep track of these and ensure that the database is closed at the end?

Answer (score 1):

I asked my JS ninja friend, and he said to use [semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29). This sounded daunting but was actually incredibly easy.

```
npm install semaphore --save
```

Package page [here](https://npmjs.org/package/semaphore). Then, for each of my database calls, I did this:

```
sem.take(function () {
  Object.find({key: value}, function () {
    sem.leave(); // (I don't need the database anymore)
    // tons of other code
  });
});
```

Then I made sure that all of that code runs before this:

```
sem.take(function () {
  sem.leave();
  db.close();
});
```

I think I probably could use a deeper understanding of what's going on, but this is working for now.